# Condition as a column named using AS "name" in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to count line that has columns which been repeated (their value) more than x times in mysql, every time I try to execute this query I get an error :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    idLogin, count(idLogin ) AS "cou" 
FROM 
   `products` AS t
GROUP BY 
    idLogin
HAVING 
    t.cou > 2
```

why this error is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one

```
SELECT DISTINCT   idLogin, count(idLogin ) AS cou  FROM   `products` 
GROUP BY idLogin HAVING cou > 2
```

Answer (score 1):

you can put that expression `count(idLogin )`  directly in having clouse....

it will not give any error.. and will be more understable as well....

or else you can do one thing  -

```
select idLogin,cou from (
SELECT DISTINCT   idLogin, count(idLogin ) AS cou  
FROM   products 
GROUP BY idLogin ) t
where t.cou >2
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the double quotes from the aliased column name.

MySQL uses single back-quotes for escaping table and column names, not double quotes.

Comment: MySQL supports double-quotes for delimited identifiers if you `SET SQL_MODE = ANSI` or `ANSI_QUOTES`.

Answer (score 0):

The correlation name `t` does not have a column `cou`.  Just use this:

```
HAVING cou > 2
```

PS: `DISTINCT` is redundant in your query.  The `GROUP BY` ensures there will only be one row per distinct value of `idLogin`.